# Algorithm: Pick a random number based on totals

Tags: c#, vb.net, random

What I do is pick a random item from a list. I then need to wait a random interval based on the total items in the list.

For example; if there is 20 items in the list, wait somewhere between 1 second and 2 seconds.
If there are 10 items in the list, wait somewhere between 1 and 3 seconds favouring the higher.
If there is 1 or 2 items in the list, wait somewhere between 5 and 10 seconds.
These numbers I just made up but you get the gist. More items = pick a quicker wait time; less items, pick a longer wait time.

I was wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing this in .NET without having to use 800 if blocks to achieve this.

Comment: You could do `Thread.Sleep((1 / NumberOfItems) * SomeMagicNumber)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help Alexei. I'm not sure why this was closed as being off-topic. It was a genuine issue that surely I could not be the first to come across. The reason listed too was nonsense.

Comment: @DmitriTrofimov: that is not a bad idea (minus the sleep portion), thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to map a value (possibly from range of values) to as result (pair upper/lower bound). It can be done with either direct [lookup table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table) if you have small number of possible values or binary search in list of ranges:

Complete list of ranges with direct lookup:

```
  int itemCount = 2; // make sure it less than number of elements in ranges.
  var random = new Random();
  var ranges = new Tuple<int, int>[] { 
      Tuple.Create(0, 1), // value for 0 
      Tuple.Create(5, 10), // value for 1 item
      Tuple.Create(5, 10), // value for 2 items        
       Tuple.Create(1, 2), // value for 3 items
      };
   var value = random.NextDouble() * ranges[itemCount].Item1 + 
        ranges[itemCount].Item2 - ranges[itemCount].Item1;
```

List of points where value of "function" changes:

```
int itemCount = 5;
var random = new Random();
var ranges = new Tuple<int, double, double>[] { 
    Tuple.Create(2, 5.0, 10.0), // value for 0-2 items        
    Tuple.Create(2, 5.0, 10.0), // value for 2-10 items        
    Tuple.Create(10, 1.0, 3.0), // value for 10-20 items        
    Tuple.Create(20, 1.0, 2.0), // value for 20+ items
};

// linear search through table, replace with binary search for 10+ items
var range = ranges[0];
for (var i = 0; i < ranges.Length;i++)
{ 
    if (ranges[i].Item1 >= itemCount) 
         break;
    range = ranges[i];
}
var value = random.NextDouble() * range.Item2 + range.Item3 - range.Item2;
```